# remove <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"> from json response in java android studio

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I'm getting this response from api:

```xml
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
[{"ActID":845,"ActName":"Current Liabilities","amount":0.0},
{"ActID":387,"ActName":"K.Ramalinga Raju - Capital","amount":0.0},
{"ActID":728,"ActName":"Krlr - Airport Land","amount":0.0},
{"ActID":746,"ActName":"Krlr - Airport Land Polls","amount":0.0},
{"ActID":842,"ActName":"kRLR - AMLPM-Kom Prawns ponds","amount":0.0},
{"ActID":763,"ActName":"Krlr - Giet Land Cement Polls","amount":0.0},
{"ActID":770,"ActName":"krlr - Matha Projects Llp","amount":0.0},
{"ActID":490,"ActName":"KRLR - Tadipudi Fish Ponds","amount":0.0},
{"ActID":586,"ActName":"Krlr Palm Oil Plantation","amount":0.0},
{"ActID":493,"ActName":"Krlr Travelling","amount":0.0},
{"ActID":805,"ActName":"KRLR-DRAWINGS","amount":0.0},
{"ActID":821,"ActName":"KRLR-Petty Expenses","amount":0.0},
{"ActID":401,"ActName":"Kvsn Raju","amount":0.0},
{"ActID":7,"ActName":"Profit & Loss - Current Year","amount":0.0},
{"ActID":8,"ActName":"Profit & Loss - Previous Year","amount":0.0}
]</string>
```

How to parse this json in volley in android studio

Comment: if it's string use `myString.replace(STRING_TO_BE_REMOVED, "")`

Comment: not working in that way

Comment: try converting the response to string and remove that and convert again to json